# Conditional expectancy proof

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

In the formal definition of conditional expectancy i have found this identity:
For  any $A∈F$ we have $∫_A E(X|F) dP=∫_A Xd P$, that is $X=E(X|F)$, where X is a random variable 
but not the proof for it, when i try to do it by myself i get that the conditional expectancy equals $E(X)$ , what am i doing wrong?

Comment: If $X$ is already measurable on $(\Omega, F,P)$ then  $E(X|F)=X$ is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i mean yeah, but why?? where can i find the proof for it?

Comment: As KaviRamaMurthy said if $ X $ is $F$-measurable (and integrable or positive) then by uniqueness of the conditional expectation, we have $E(X|F) = X $ a.s.